# Unable to install correct Linux headers

Tags: kernel, apt, kali-linux, vmware

Im trying to install VMWare workstation player on my Kali Linux Os.
However, I encounter a kernel issue when trying to start VMware:

> C header files matching your running kernel were not found.  Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions.

I tried installing the correct headers using **apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**, which gave me the following output:

> Reading package lists...
>   Building dependency tree...
>   Reading state information...
>
> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
>
> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64'

**apt search linux-headers**

```
aufs-dkms - DKMS files to build and install aufs
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-all - All header files for Linux 4.14 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 4.14 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-amd64
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-rt
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-hppa-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-m68k-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64r6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64r6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32r6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32r6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsr6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsr6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpcspe-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-s390x-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sh4-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sparc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-686 - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-686
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-686-pae
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-all-i386 - All header files for Linux 4.14 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae
linux-headers-686 - Header files for Linux 686 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-686-pae - Header files for Linux 686-pae configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-rt-686-pae - Header files for Linux rt-686-pae configuration (meta-package)

linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.12.0-kali1
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1-amd64
```

**apt search linux-image**

```
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-amd64
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-amd64 - Linux 4.14 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-amd64
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64 - Linux 4.14 for 64-bit PCs, PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-rt-amd64
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-rt-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package), PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-rt-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-686 - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-686
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-686-pae
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae - Header files for Linux 4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686 - Linux 4.14 for older PCs
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae - Linux 4.14 for modern PCs
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae - Linux 4.14 for modern PCs, PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-rt-686-pae
linux-image-686 - Linux for older PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-686-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux 686 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-686-pae - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-686-pae-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux 686-pae configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-rt-686-pae - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package), PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-rt-686-pae-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux rt-686-pae configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-4.13.0-kali1-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.13.0-kali1-amd64
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1-amd64
linux-image-4.12.0-kali1-amd64 - Linux 4.12 for 64-bit PCs
```

**Tried so far**
I already tried updating my system using the apt: update, autoremove, dist-upgrade, upgrade etc...

```
root@Anonymous:~# uname -r
4.12.0-kali1-amd64
root@Anonymous:~# sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod trusty InRelease        
Hit:3 http://ftp1.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you rebooted since you updated your system?

Comment: Yes I did reboot

Comment: I am using live usb /w persistence

Comment: Your kernel is not up to date, the only headers that seem available are for kernel versions `4.13.0-kali1` and `4.14.0-kali1`. However you are running `4.12.0-kali1`. Did you try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in this order ?

Comment: Yes, did it in that order. I'm gonna try to remove old headers manually now

Comment: Did not help... Is there any way I can fix this manually?

Comment: "I am using live usb /w persistence" ??? But you can't add any apps to the USB. They will be lost on reboot. It's like a Live-CD. It will save SOME things in the persistence partition but not everything.

Comment: Yes I can add apps there.. So far this seems to be working fine. How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: **sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && reboot**. After reboot **sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**.

Answer (score 0):

The [Official Kali Rolling Release](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) does not seem to have anything for `Linux 4.12`.  However, it seems that the Lug mirror that you are using does include some of the older files.

Seemingly, the only Official Kali release that includes `Linux 4.12` is [2017.2](http://old.kali.org/kali/dists/2017.2/)

```
$ grep -n headers-4.1 Packages_2017.2

851688:Package: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all
851694:Depends: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all-amd64 (= 4.12.6-1kali6)
851698:Filename: pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all_4.12.6-1kali6_amd64.deb
851708:Package: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all-amd64
851714:Depends: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64 (= 4.12.6-1kali6)
851718:Filename: pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.12.6-1kali6_amd64.deb
851728:Package: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
851734:Depends: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-common (= 4.12.6-1kali6), linux-kbuild-4.12, linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86
851738:Filename: pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64_4.12.6-1kali6_amd64.deb
851747: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64, and can be used for building
851751:Package: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-common
851761:Filename: pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-common_4.12.6-1kali6_all.deb
851770: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-(flavour) package, matching the flavour of the
851779:Depends: linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
```

Perhaps, the Lug repo has some problems with missing packages.  You may want to re-image your installation using the latest Official Kali release or use the official `2017.2` repo.

However, Kali Linux is a specialized distribution and so can be rather difficult to setup and maintain.  If you have no need of the specialized tools, I highly recommend choosing a different distro.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel updating on Kali live was addressed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364457/how-to-change-the-boot-kernel-of-a-usb-live-w-persistent-running-kali/373801?noredirect=1#comment664859_373801)

Simply put, the new kernel and initrd you want to boot from and should be copied to

```
/live/vmlinuz
/live/initrd.img
```

with those names.

Thinking about this, any update of the kernel you performed will probably (naturally) go to the persistence partition and so not be available early enough for the live boot.